# Set container size width and height with one function argument

Tags: javascript, css, containers

I have a container `grid`, that I'm trying to set the width and height of proportionally by passing that one number as an argument `tiles` in my `createSketchGrid` function.  I'm using the variable `gridSize` to take the arguments `tiles` and multiply it by itself.  The result is a container that is quite a bit wider than its height.

I'm not quite sure how to set this evenly and multiplying it doesn't make it proportional, either.  Is there a way to set the width and height to be the same if I use this one argument? I also think that setting the container's display property to `flex` may be part of the problem as well.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('#grid');
const userInput = document.querySelector('#user-input');
grid.style.fontSize = '1em';
// Set pixel width and height
let wdt = '1.25em';
let hgt = '1.25em';

// Ask the user for the number of tiles for the sketch grid
function getUserInput() {
  let input = parseInt(prompt(`Please enter the grid size you'd like`));
  input <= 100 || !isNaN(input)
    ? createSketchGrid(input)
    : alert('Please enter a valid number less than or equal to 100.');
}

// Event listener to create tiles in mouseover
function setTiles(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('fill');
}

function deleteTiles(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('fill');
}
// Create the grid
function createSketchGrid(tiles) {
  let gridSize = tiles * tiles;
  for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    let tile = document.createElement('div');
    tile.style.width = wdt;
    tile.style.height = hgt;
    grid.appendChild(tile);
    tile.addEventListener('mouseover', setTiles);
  }
}

userInput.addEventListener('click', getUserInput);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.1em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex: 0 0 32em;
}

.fill {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Etch A Sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="title">Etch A Sketch</h1>
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <button id="user-input" class="btn user-input" value="Grid Size">Grid Size</button>
    <div id="grid" class="grid">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure the problem is that your grid isn't a grid but rather a long line of individual etch-a-sketch squares. You can (and should) use CSS grid instead of CSS flexbox for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS grid, we can define how many columns we want (here I have just used the regular `repeat(..., ...)` method), and we can also change the width of the grid to match.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('#grid');
const userInput = document.querySelector('#user-input');
grid.style.fontSize = '1em';
// Set pixel width and height
let wdt = '1.25em';
let hgt = '1.25em';

// Ask the user for the number of tiles for the sketch grid
function getUserInput() {
  let input = parseInt(prompt(`Please enter the grid size you'd like`));
  input <= 100 || !isNaN(input)
    ? createSketchGrid(input)
    : alert('Please enter a valid number less than or equal to 100.');
}

// Event listener to create tiles in mouseover
function setTiles(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('fill');
}

function deleteTiles(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('fill');
}
// Create the grid
function createSketchGrid(tiles) {
  let gridSize = tiles * tiles;
  for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    let tile = document.createElement('div');
    tile.style.width = wdt;
    tile.style.height = hgt;
    grid.appendChild(tile);
    tile.addEventListener('mouseover', setTiles);
  }
  // change style
  grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${tiles}, 1fr)`;
  // calculate new width
  grid.style.width = `calc(${wdt} * ${tiles} + 0.1em * ${tiles - 1})`;
}

userInput.addEventListener('click', getUserInput);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(0, 1em);
  gap: 0.1em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.fill {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Etch A Sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="title">Etch A Sketch</h1>
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <button id="user-input" class="btn user-input" value="Grid Size">Grid Size</button>
    <div id="grid" class="grid">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```